# Can I say "hit the bushes" to mean escape?

Tags: creative-writing, metaphors

Can I say "hit the bushes" to mean escape?

I simply want to verify if this expression exists. I know "beat the bushes" to describe a thorough search.

Comment: I'm voting to migrate this to English.SE as it's about the correctness of an English phrase, and not about writing.

Comment: @F1Krazy I disagree. We have a metaphor tag, and I am in mid-answer. I suggest migrating it back to Writing.

Comment: It's not a familiar expression to me, in the US.  I'm vaguely recalling that there's a similar expression which would be a better fit, but it's not coming to me.

Comment: @Nai54 My apologies, but the question has already been migrated. I do believe this is more suited to here than to Writing.SE, but let's see what the community here think; if they agree, they can close the question and that'll kick it back to Writing, where I can reopen it.

Comment: “Hit the road” is a common idiom for this purpose.

Comment: This sounds to me like you've misremembered the Australian term for the wilderness ... "the bush." If you're in Australia, and you're escaping into back country, I think you could get away with "hit the bush" (although you'd have to ask an Australian to see if I've got it right).

Comment: This is not a US phrase, so readers over here would not understand it.

Comment: @PeterShor Australians talk about "the bush", as a singular, uncountable term for the wooded parts of the country. I have never heard it pluralised as "bushes". That would sound quite wrong. The more general term for the uninhabited regions of the country is "the outback".

Comment: Canadians also use this term, so “hit the bush” or “hit the sticks” would be uncommon but understandable. Maybe “hit the bushes” has meaning in other locales, but if we’ve ruled out Australia, Canada, the UK and the US, it would have to be pretty specialized.

Comment: I’d have said one “hits the bushes” when there’s no latrine handy.

Answer (score 2):

### Can you use it? Yes.
Should you? Maybe.

Really, you can make up or use any sort of saying or metaphor that you would like in a novel. The only basic guideline is that *it should make sense*. The metaphor

> like a bull in a china shop

makes sense **without surrounding context**. You can obviously tell it goes along the lines of someone who breaks things or is insensible in a situation where you should be careful.

However, if I just made up an obscure idiom/metaphor, would you be able to decipher it? Try this:

> like a stick figure in the rain

The meaning? Well, I intended to mean someone who can easily slip through precarious situations unharmed. You probably didn't get that though, you would have needed surrounding context.

So, in summary, **your idiom *should* make sense *without surrounding context* in order to work**.

### **Specifically, should you use "hit the bushes"?**

Well, I for one, did not understand it without the explanation behind it, so maybe not? It's up to you. It's always best to stay simple when using idioms, so your reader does not misinterpret them. Think about it, would you need surrounding context for "hit the bushes"?

Also, be careful that no one mixes up "hit the bushes" with "beat around the bushes" as the two sound similar.

### Is this phrase common?

Apparently, it's been used before. See the below chart:

[image]

-[Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hit%20the%20bushes&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chit%20the%20bushes%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Chit%20the%20bushes%3B%2Cc0)

But, simply googling the term yields no results. It seems like a low use idiom.

### TLDR

You may use it if you would like to, but only if you are *100%* confident that the reader will understand it. If you do use it, surround it with helpful context.

It also has been used before, but not super often.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there were bushes, the phrase would not be understood.

See Google Ngrams for the search terms **[hit the bushes,hit the trail](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hit%20the%20bushes%2C%20hit%20the%20trail&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=27&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chit%20the%20bushes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chit%20the%20trail%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Chit%20the%20bushes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chit%20the%20trail%3B%2Cc0)** where it is used only literally (with "hit" = start/enter into) and without the meaning of "to escape" - other than where there are actually bushes.

We Were Heroes: The Journal of Scott Pendleton Collins* Walter Dean Myers · 2012 *Their first wave slowed as they hit the bushes and the grenades tore into them.*

Magic Apples: Reflections to Mull - Page 233 Lee Steels · 2014 Page 233
*Then we used our Mother's biggest sieve to hit the bushes. If it was done correctly, only the ripe blueberries came off.*

The Making of a Healer: Teachings of My Oneida Grandmother Russell FourEagles · 2014 Page 105 *So everyone started making breakfast and hit the bushes for latrine duty, and at 0700 the sergeant told me to check the ambushes.*

> I know "beat the bushes" to describe a thorough search.

That is quite uncommon and rather old-fashioned.